# how to compare two slightly different images rendered by two programs

Tags: image-comparison

I rendered similar images using a Vulkan and an OpenGL ES program. Supposedly the two programs should generate the same result, so I want to test it by comparing the two images. However, the camera settings, the size of the images and so on make it hard to compare images directly. Does anyone have some ideas about this?

Thank you!

Comment: How different are the camera for this, are the cameras in different positions or is it just the aspect ratio that is different?

Comment: What is aspect ratio?

Comment: so I made sure gl_position and all sorts of position variables are set the same. adjusted mvp matrices and cam pos, and all panned out well.